# how to translate list from a file?

Tags: python

```
fo=open("sample.txt","r")
item=fo.readlines()
fo.close()

replacements = (('4','A'),('8','b'),('3','e'),('5','s'),('7','t'),('@','a'),('3','e'),('0','o'))
new_string = item
for new, old in replacements:
new_string = new_string.replace(new, old)

print ( new_string)
```

I have written the following code but does not read my list. My goal is translate the list.

Comment: You'll need to define "does not work". What are you expecting to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: Please indent your code properly so we can tell what you're actually doing. Also please include the error that occurs if any, and an excerpt of sample.txt.

Comment: `readlines` returns a list, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.translate()` to use a translation table for faster translation.  Here is an example:

```
with open("sample.txt","r") as fo:
    lines = fo.readlines()

replacements = {'4':'A', '8':'b', '3':'e', '5':'s', '7':'t', '@':'a', '3':'e', '0':'o'}
trans_table = str.maketrans(replacements)
for line in lines:
    print(line, end="")
    new_line = line.translate(trans_table)
    print(new_line)
```

OUTPUT:

```
h3llo 70 y0u
hello to you

4 8377er w0rld 70d@y
A better world today
```

Comment: thank you.. but how do I ask the user to give a  the name of the file they want to have translated, and the name they want
for the translated file.

Comment: @mandy You can print a message telling the user to enter the name of the file to translate, and use the `input()` function to read user input: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Comment: I got an error..                                                                                          Leet file name? leet.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/files/leet_translator.py", line 7, in <module>
    leet= int(input("Leet file name? "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'leet.txt'

Comment: You should not be trying to convert the file name to and `int`.  Once you get the file name from `input()`, then you can use `open()` to open the file, as is done in the above code with "sample.txt"